# Animator Glitching when skipping from one key frame to another

Tags: animation, armature

So I'm making a walk animation, and when I move directly from one key frame to another the mesh and armature glitch. Like when I press the button to skip forwards to the next frame from frame one to two the foot bone twists around on the x axis several times. Some thing similar happens when I move from two to one. But when I play the animation not glitches occur.
This makes it impossible to compare translation between frames.
How do I fix this? I have had problems with things like this in Unity and all I had to do was delete a cache of data to fix it. But I have no idea where you would do that with blender.
Also I would upload my blend file with this post but I don't know where to upload it too.

[image]

Comment: Upload your file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Sounds like a [cyclic dependency](http://julienduroure.com/en/2014/12/dependency-cycle-detected/).

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6215" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6215/)
Here it is, and ya the problem does look alot like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a cyclic [dependency](http://julienduroure.com/en/2014/12/dependency-cycle-detected/).

When you move the foot controler, the console output reads. (Screenshot at the end of the post.) Open the console from the infobar menu: *Window > Toggle System Console* on windows.

```
Dependency cycle detected:
  shin.L depends on thigh.L through Parent Relation.
  foot.L depends on shin.L through Parent Relation.
  IKKnee.L depends on foot.L through Parent Relation.
  thigh.L depends on IKKnee.L through IK Constraint.
```

I suggest parenting the *IKKnee* bones to the *IKFoot* bones. Then there will be a hierarchical dependency.

[image: cyclic dependency]

Comment: Ya that seemed to solve it thanks